# ODBC/DSN mapped drive with php

Tags: ms-access, odbc, drive, dsn

I am actually trying to connect to a `.mdb` Database with ODBC per PHP.

On my localhost it works great, but when transferred to my mapped server it isn't anymore.
I know, it is a problem of UNC and mapped drives. I already tried

```
\\Users\[...]\test.mdb
```

and

```
C:\[...]\test.mdb
```

First one throws S1009 as error, the second one S1000. What can I do? It is a System DNS on a Windows Server 2008, ODBC is running, no Access installed.

Answer (score 1):

When you map drives or use UNC Paths, the files there will be requested in the security context of the webserver. With close to 100% probability the webserver user has no access to the fileshares in your LAN.

Keep it that way amd have the mdb reside on a drive that is local to the webserver, if ever possible.

Comment: Right. I copied the .mdb to the public root of the webserver and made a new dsn to it, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're using a proper UNC path. For example: **\\Computername\Share\test.mdb**. StackOverflow might have eaten any double-backslashes you entered, so this may be a moot point.

Second, make sure the share's permissions are set up for whichever account runs the PHP script. This is the cause of most "scripts can't access a share" errors in my experience.